# How to write loop on shell script

Tags: bash, shell, jq

How to write loop to iterate the below command for 10 times for variable i.

```
_RESULT=$(curl -sgG "${CURL_OPTS[@]}" --data-urlencode "query=${PROMETHEUS_QUERY}" "${PROMETHEUS_SERVER}/api/v1/query" | jq -r '.data.result[**i**]')
```

Comment: Show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `for i in ...; do ...; done`

Comment: `for i in {21..30}; do ....; done`